# Multinomial Theorem Formula

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$$\sum_{k_1 + \cdots +k_m =n} \frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_m!}. (k_1 + 1).(k_2 + 1)\cdots(k_m + 1) $$

We are given N = M - 2

I read about Multinomial Theorem, this one looks similar to it, are there any ways to calculate this in a easier way. Can this be further generalised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hint

The multinomial theorem states
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m)^n=\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_m!}x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_m^{k_m}
$$
Multiply both sides by $x_1x_2\cdots x_m$:
$$
x_1x_2\cdots x_m(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m)^n=\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_m!}x_1^{k_1+1}\cdots x_m^{k_m+1}
$$
Now, partial differentiate both sides with respect to $x_1$. Note that the $x_1^{k_1+1}$ on the right is replaced with $(k_1+1)x_1^{k_1}$; we have a $k_1+1$ now, which is what you want. Therefore, you should partial differentiate with respect to all the other variables as well. After plugging in $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_m=1$, the RHS is then exactly what you want. All the remains is to compute what the partial differentiating does to the LHS, which will probability get a little messy but should be OK.

It appears that the result of the differentiations is
$$
\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,m\}}\left(\prod_{i\in S}x_i\right)\binom{n}{|S|}(|S|)!(x_1+\dots+x_m)^{n-|S|}
$$
which after substituting one for all variables implies the summation is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}j\binom{n}jj!\cdot m^{n-j}.
$$
This is based on seeing a pattern after trying this for $m=2,3$, so you still need to prove that this actually is correct.

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Comment: Hey can you help me out with this one also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220350/deduce-the-multinomial-formula

Comment: @ayushkedia No, I cannot.